# overriding ColorBox open/close transition effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colorbox

right now the [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) transition is set to "zoom-in" on opening and "fadeOut" when it's closing. Is there a way to change this?

I would like it to "Zoom-Out" upon closing, maybe using a JQuery hide(500) function?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more precise? What is it supposed to "zoom-out"?
Post some code to explain it better.

For what I got you have to set properly the *transition* property.